# Is it possible to submit form in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I've got an iframe `bar` and I want to put the result of my form submit in there. In a loop. Many times.

Here's my code:

```
function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        submitForm(i);
    }
}

function submitForm(page) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");

    form.method = "GET";
    form.action = "http://isup.me";
    form.target = "bar";
    form.id = "form" + page;

    var id = document.createElement("input"); 
    id.value = page;
    id.name = "id";
    form.appendChild(id);   

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

In the network tab I can only see last `GET` request with parameter `9` is performed.

PS. I cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` because of the same origin policy.

Comment: Of course the browser cancels the current request, as soon as you make a new one targeting the same window instance.

Comment: So, I should have a separate iframe for each request. I did a quick test and you're right :)

Comment: It may not be a great idea to hammer an external site with multiple simultaneous form requests.  Consider treating this like a web scraping task (since that's effectively what you're doing) -- respect robots.txt, throttle your requests to a reasonable speed, etc.

Comment: @DanielBeck yeah, sure, it's just a simulation what I would do manually, in example, there's a comment section that only loads 10 of entries and I have to press `next` button to load another 10 entries. I just want to see them all at once ;)